# Getting "401 - unauthorized" when accessing the prestashop api webservice

Tags: python, php, amazon-web-services, prestashop

I have a fresh installation of Prestashop 1.7 on AWS Lightsail. Unfortunately when I try to access the Webservice API in the browser I can't authenticate and I get an 401 - unauthorized.

Using Python I see that I get the "Welcome to Prestashop Webservice, please enter the authentication key as the login ..." from the dispatcher.php script.

The Key is set up in the backend and activated.

Answer (score 0):

https://wordcodepress.com/prestashop-1-7-webservice-api-401-unauthorized/ Had the solution, seems like dispatcher.php did not get the key properly and some fixes in the .htaccess are necessary:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
RewriteRule . - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]
```

in the fresh lightsail installation I put the lines right behind the API rewrite statement:

```
RewriteRule . - [E=REWRITEBASE:/]
RewriteRule ^api(?:/(.*))?$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}webservice/dispatcher.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]

 
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
RewriteRule . - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]
```